# How to keep a 110V appliance ON for 1 minute every 5 minutes, without arduino?

Tags: control, duty-cycle, appliances

I need to turn ON an appliance (110V, 0.5A) for 1 minute every 5 minutes. The immediate solution that comes to mind is arduino/raspberry-pi and with a relay.

What kind of circuits would help me accomplish that?

Comment: VTC - This is a basic shopping question which is not supported here. That said look into a WIFI enabled smart plug that supports scheduled On/Off behavior. You may be able to program it to cycle your appliance. Alternatively a custom software on a PC may be able to talk to the WIFI enabled smart plug to do the same thing.

Comment: Any programmable digital timer?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using a 555 astable circuit, as shown below:

[image]

using values that I calculated from [this 555 calculator](http://www.csgnetwork.com/ne555timer2calc.html):

```
R1 = 383K
R2 = 127K
C = 680 µF
```

which gives an on time of 240.3 seconds, and an off time of 59.8 seconds, and a duty cycle of 80.06%.  Note the on/off ratio is just opposite of what you want, so you will need an inverter on the output.  This can easily be done by using a P-channel MOSFET as a high-side switch driving a relay as shown, since it turns on with a 0 level and off with a high level.

Note that you will only be able to get capacitors with at best ±10 tolerance, so if you need fairly exact timing you may need to fiddle with the resistor values some.